# How to send a notification to the new user to reset password

Tags: php, laravel

in my project only admin can register users .. once user registered an email sent to him with a redirect link to password reset page

I tried to use the notification to do that so I made:

```
php artisan make:notification NewUserPasswordCreate
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;
use App\Notifications\NewUserPasswordCreate;

class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    use Notifiable;
    use LaratrustUserTrait;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function createAcount()
    {
        $token = app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($this);
        return $this->notify(new NewUserPasswordCreate($token));
    }
}
```

Store function in UserController

**UserController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'     => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'email'    => 'required|unique:users',
            'civilNum'  => 'required|size:12',
        ]);

        if ($request->has('password') && !empty($request->password)) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'password' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            ]);
            $password = Hash::make($request->password);
        } else {
            $length = 10;
            $keyspace = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $str= '';
            $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
            for ($i=0; $i < $length; ++$i) { 
                $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)]; 
            }
            $password = $str;
        }
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->civilNum = $request->civilNum;
        $user->password = $password;   

        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->save();

        if ($user->save()) {
            return redirect()->route('users.index');
        } else {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Sorry, a problem occured while creating the user.');
            return redirect()->route('users.create');
        }
    }
```

**NewUserPasswordCreate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NewUserPasswordCreate extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $link = url( "/password/reset/?token=" . $this->token );

        return ( new MailMessage )
            ->view('reset.emailer')
            ->from('info@example.com')
            ->subject( 'Reset your password' )
            ->line( "Hey, We've successfully changed the text " )
            ->action( 'Reset Password', $link )
            ->attach('reset.attachment')
            ->line( 'Thank you!' );
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make it work  .. thank you.

(Sorry .. I'm begginer)

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passwords). There's a guide to accomplish [that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passwords).

Comment: I want a help to edit my code .. thank you

Comment: `$this->token` is undefined in your `toMail` function. Also you will need to make sure you have a template located in `resources/views/reset/emailer.blade.php` since you have `->view('reset.emailer')`.

Comment: fine .. what is the code in UserController after saving the user ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to notify a user you need to call the `notify()` method on the `User` object that has a `Notifiable` trait.

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->notify(new App\Notifications\NewUserPasswordCreate);
```

See the [docs for notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#sending-notifications).